# Changing data table td value in php

Tags: php, html

I am populating data table dynamically. In here I am assigning values to td, in IF clause based on the serial number. I want to change the assigned value of specific td in else part. here is my code.

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
        if($ser_no != $task->serial_number){
          $officer_name="";
          $ser_no =$task->serial_number;
          $officer_name =$officer_name.",". $task->name;
        ?>



   <tr style=" border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; "> 
    <td style=" border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; " id="{{$task->task_user_id}}_officer">{{$officer_name}}</td>

     <?php
    }else{
      $officer_name =$officer_name.",". $task->name;
    }


                 ?>  
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

I want to change the assigned td value in else part

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to place your else clause before the TDs are printed.

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
        if($ser_no != $task->serial_number){
          $officer_name="";
          $ser_no =$task->serial_number;
          $officer_name =$officer_name.",". $task->name;
    }else{
      $officer_name =$officer_name.",". $task->name;
    }          
  ?>

   <tr style=" border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; "> 
    <td style=" border-left:1px solid; border-right:1px solid; border-top:1px solid; " id="{{$task->task_user_id}}_officer">{{$officer_name}}</td>

    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Once the markup is sent to the client it cannot be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.Thats mean I have to run for loop two times. scenario is, I want to show assigned tasks. each task has been assigned to more than one officer. So I want to show officers by separating comma in one column, task and dead line is another two columns

Comment: Just think of the markup like about sth that has already been printed and cannot be changed. So you have resolve all your logic before creating any markup.